# where can I get a ps/2 driver

Tags: drivers, ps2-keyboard

I am using a microsoft natural multimedia keyboard 1.0a and my computer has no ps/2 port so I got a ps/2 to USB adapter. The keyboard won't type anything however, not even the basics. I think I need a driver for the keyboard. Where can I get one?

Comment: The basic functions should work by default without drivers, but here is the [downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads#keyboard) page.  If @NicoleHamilton's suggestion doesn't work, it could possibly just be a power issue.  One of my friends had to solder in a USB header to one once due to a similar behaving issue.  Of course, if you were to do that - be careful of power consumption and limits.

Comment: For such an essential device as a keyboard, its driver is built into the kernel by default (for OSes intended for PCs anyway).  When someone writes *"should work ... without drivers"* or *"you don't need a driver for it"*, either they should have written *"you don't have to **install** the driver"* or they are not aware that every device in a well-written OS has a driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a better adapter.  They aren't all the same.  Here's the brand I've been using from [clickykeyboards.com](http://www.clickykeyboards.com) the last 5 years or so.  I still prefer the old 1980s clicky IBM keyboards (also available from this same company) on all my machines, so I have several of these adapters and they work with every machine I've tried.

[PS/2 to USB adapter converter for keyboards](http://www.clickykeyboards.com/index.cfm/fa/items.main/parentcat/11298/subcatid/0/id/124184)
[image: PS/2 to USB adapter]

**Added:**

The same adapter also appears to be available elsewhere, e.g., [USBGear](http://www.usbgear.com/computer_cable_details.cfm?sku=USBG-1KPS2&cats=114&catid=114,106,626,142) and [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSJFJS).

Comment: That is probably the problem. I got a $1.35 adapter off eBay.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a driver for it. Not all PS/2 to USB adapters work on all keyboards and mice. The keyboard must be built to support that feature, and they will usually ship with one.

If it doesn't type on your computer, the first thing I would try is another keyboard, or else trying the keyboard on another computer. Does that work? Great, we can move on from there. If it still doesn't work, it's probably time for another keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

ps/2 KBD is a one wire data pin, and 1 clock
USB is 2 pins and is differential. and no clock pin, (not compat)
they are not compatible at all raw. or wired raw copper jumps.

The USB port can be limited to 50 or 100 ma, and cant run any 150-200mA
ps/2 keyboards at all. (old laptops, get USB-C)

that is why the clickly adapter above has  processor inside to do that
and do the USB wake up protocol and all that.
best used on full power desktop (usb power)

why not buy a usb gaming keyboard with cherry switches real
those switches come in many feels,, even clickity,  im using one now.
from CorSair

copper wire adapters for $1 are useless here.
not only that ramming 5vdc data signal in to any USB port is well, not too smart.IMO  why blow up any mobo, tell me?

sorry 6years late but for the records, this is fact and more.
there are more facts why it wont work.
run the w10, i8420prt.sys driver and turn it on in the registry.